# Aligning matrices, normalization. Calculating coefficients.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, least-squares

So as a pre-task for my upcoming exam this is one of the rehearsal assignments. I can't wrap my head around this one at all, haven't seen anything like it earlier, and I can't seem to find any solutions.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Least squares via normal equations**

The linear system is
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{A} c & = \mathbb{B} \\
%
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 2 \\
 1 & 3 \\
 1 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 b \\
 a \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
&=
%
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 \\
 4 \\
 5 \\
 6 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\end{align}
$$
The normal equations are
$$
\begin{align}
%
\mathbb{A}^{T}\mathbb{A} a &= \mathbb{A}^{T}\mathbb{B} \\[2pt]
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 4 & 10 \\
 10 & 30 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 b \\
 a \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
&=
%
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 18 \\
 50 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\end{align}
%
$$
with the solution
$$
\boxed{
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 b \\
 a \\
\end{array}
\right)_{LS}
=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 \\
 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
}
$$
The residual error vector is
$$
 r_{LS} = \mathbf{0},
$$
the fit is exact, which implies the data vector $\mathbf{B}$ is in the column space of $\mathbf{A}$. The prescription in terms of column vectors is $\mathbb{B}=2\mathbb{A}_{1} + \mathbb{A}_{2}$.

**Least squares via calculus**

The target of minimization, the merit function, sums over the rows $r$ and columns $c$:
$$
 M(a,b) = \sum_{r=1}^{2}\sum_{c=1}^{2} \left( \mathbf{A}_{rc} - a \mathbf{B}_{rc} - b\right)^{2}
$$
which leads to
$$
\begin{align}
%
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
%
 \sum^{2}_{r=1}\mathbf{A}_{r,1}\mathbf{A}_{r,1} & 
 \sum^{2}_{r=1}\mathbf{A}_{r,1}\mathbf{A}_{r,2} \\
%
 \sum^{2}_{r=1}\mathbf{A}_{r,2}\mathbf{A}_{r,1} & 
 \sum^{2}_{r=1}\mathbf{A}_{r,2}\mathbf{A}_{r,2} \\
%
\end{array}
\right)
%
%
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 b \\
 a \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
&=
%
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
%
 \sum^{2}_{r=1}\mathbf{A}_{r,1}\mathbf{B}_{r} \\
% 
 \sum^{2}_{r=1}\mathbf{A}_{r,2}\mathbf{B}_{r} \\
%
\end{array}
\right)
%
\end{align}
%
$$
which yields the same solutions.